# How to config spring-session to support HeaderHttpSessionStrategy and CookieHttpSessionStrategy in one application?

Tags: spring, rest, httpsession, spring-session, json-web-token

I have a project want to support android,ios,pc web. I try to use https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session, can it be just config in an application to support HttpSession and rest token?

if it can,how i can config it?

Answer (score 2):

One thing that worked for me was to reimplement the `***HttpSessionStrategy` using code from both Cookie and Header implementations.

You can see the concrete implementation of these classes here:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/http/HeaderHttpSessionStrategy.java
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spring-projects/spring-session/master/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/http/CookieHttpSessionStrategy.java

So the `getRequestedSessionId` becomes:

```
public String getRequestedSessionId(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // header part
        String sessionId = request.getHeader(headerName);
        if(sessionId != null && !sessionId.isEmpty())
            return sessionId;

        // cookie part
        Map<String,String> sessionIds = getSessionIds(request);
        String sessionAlias = getCurrentSessionAlias(request);
        return sessionIds.get(sessionAlias);
    }
```

`onInvalidateSession` becomes:

```
public void onInvalidateSession(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // header part
    response.setHeader(headerName, "");

    // cookie part
    Map<String,String> sessionIds = getSessionIds(request);
    String requestedAlias = getCurrentSessionAlias(request);
    sessionIds.remove(requestedAlias);

    Cookie sessionCookie = createSessionCookie(request, sessionIds);
    response.addCookie(sessionCookie);
}
```

`onNewSession` becomes:

```
public void onNewSession(Session session, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // header part
        response.setHeader(headerName, session.getId());

        // cookie part
        Set<String> sessionIdsWritten = getSessionIdsWritten(request);
        if(sessionIdsWritten.contains(session.getId())) {
            return;
        }
        sessionIdsWritten.add(session.getId());

        Map<String,String> sessionIds = getSessionIds(request);
        String sessionAlias = getCurrentSessionAlias(request);
        sessionIds.put(sessionAlias, session.getId());
        Cookie sessionCookie = createSessionCookie(request, sessionIds);
        response.addCookie(sessionCookie);
    }
```

I used this in production for a browser/mobile REST API and it suits all my needs.

Comment: Given github link is broken. Is there any other link to refer?

Answer (score 0):

you can utilize spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor ,to overwrite the postProcessAfterInitialization() to config the SessionRepositoryFilter's httpSessionStrategy by call it's setHttpSessionStrategy() method after it's initialization in spring.